# Partition algorithm with two loops c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was given pseudo code for a partition algorithm but I'm not really sure how to implement it.

Below is the pseudo code and my implementation. Please let me know if this is correct/explain what it's doing. Right now I have a partial understanding of it but it is not correct.

Input: 0.963, 0.003, 0.0251, 0.353, 0.667, 0.838, 0.335, 0.915, 0.796, 0.833, 0.345, 0.871, 0.089, 0.888, 0.701, 0.735

Expected: 0.003 0.0251 0.089 0.335 0.345 0.353 0.667 0.701 0.735 0.796 0.833 0.838 0.871 0.888 0.915 0.963

Actual: 0.003000 0.025100 0.353000 0.667000 0.838000 0.335000 0.915000 0.796000 0.833000 0.345000 0.871000 0.089000 0.888000 0.7 01000 0.735000 0.963000
 [image]

```
int partition_data( float xdata[], int ndata, float xmiddle ) {
  int left;
  int right;
  int j,i;
  float temp;

  for(i = 0; i < xmiddle; i ++){
    if(left == right){
      left += 1;
    }
    else{
      for( j = ndata - 1; j >= xmiddle; j--){
        if(left == right){
          right -= 1;
        }
        else{
          temp = xdata[j];
          xdata[j] = xdata[i];
          xdata[i] = temp;

          right -= 1;
          if(left == right){
            left += 1;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Does it work? Did you try it?

Comment: A comment: this pseudocode could be improved substantially. Almost all comments are redundant (and visually clutter the code), the indentation (and general formatting) is off and it fails at concisely explaining what the algorithm actually does and what its invariants are.

Comment: I just posted a code review of this thanks @JoachimPileborg.

Comment: What is the value for xmiddle?

Comment: A link to the same question posted at CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112345/partition-algorithm-with-two-loops-c

Comment: I added some explanations to the algorithm here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34031666/733637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already said, both here and at Code Review, the pseudocode is quite non-standard, and hard to read (although it's not true it is mis-indented).

However, if you're not interested in improving it, but just want to implement it 'as is', here it is, word-by-word translated into C language:

```
int Partition(float X[], int ndata, float xmiddle)
{
    int left  = 0;
    int right = ndata - 1;
    while(1) {              // 'left' loop
        if(X[left] < xmiddle)
        {
            if(left == right)
                return left + 1;
            left ++;
        }
        else
            while(1) {     // 'right' loop
                if(X[right] >= xmiddle)
                {
                    if(left == right)
                        return left;
                    right --;
                }
                else
                {
                    float tmp = X[left];    // these three lines
                    X[left] = X[right];     // swap the two values
                    X[right] = tmp;         // X[left] and X[right]

                    right --;
                    if(left == right)
                        return left + 1;
                    left ++;
                    break;           // exit the 'right' loop
                }
            }     // end of 'right' loop
    }   // end of 'left' loop
} // end of Parition
```

The code is actually C, in C++ you might make it a function template with a type parameter instead of explicit `float`, so that the function may partition arrays of different types (as long as operators `<` and `>=` are defined). You might also use `std::swap` for efficient swapping data and dropping the explicit `tmp` variable.

Comment: I removed the comment at Code Review about mis-indentation a while back. Curious Cat posted at code review that he still wasn't getting the "expected" with CiaPan's above example, but the "expected" output appears to be sorted, and I'm not sure one instance of partition would sort the data.

Comment: @rcgldr Possibly the `Partition` routine is just a part of the Curious Cat's task. I admit I didn't check the data presented by OP, just concentrated on the implementation in the given language. If I have some more free time (alas not very soon) I'll try to add some explanation of *'what it's doing'*, as Curious Cat asked.

Comment: @rcgldr I added some explanations here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34031666/733637

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the assignment was to implement a full quicksort?

Quicksort with conventional pre-increment / pre-decrement Hoare partition scheme:

```
int Partition(float x[], int lo, int hi)
{
float xmiddle = x[(lo+hi)/2];
int left = lo - 1;
int right = hi + 1;
float tmp;
    while (1){
        while (x[++left]  < xmiddle);
        while (x[--right] > xmiddle);
        if(left >= right)
            break;
        tmp = x[left];
        x[left] = x[right];
        x[right] = tmp;
    }
    return right;
}

void QuickSort(float x[], int lo, int hi){
int pivot;
    if (lo < hi){
        pivot = Partition(x, lo, hi);
        QuickSort(x, lo, pivot);
        QuickSort(x, pivot+1, hi);
    }
}
```

One issue with quicksort is that a minor bug in the partition scheme may work for most data patterns and only fail for specific data patterns, making it difficult to determine if a quicksort is really bug free.

Quicksort using modified version from the psuedo code above. This works for the example data, but I'm not sure it's bug free. Partition should return an index that points to a value == xmiddle:

```
int Partition(float X[], int lo, int hi)
{
    int left  = lo;
    int right = hi;
    float xmiddle = X[(lo+hi)/2];
    float tmp;
    while(1) {
        while(X[left] < xmiddle){
            if(left == right)
                return left+1;
            left++;
        }
        while(X[right] >= xmiddle){
            if(left == right)
                return left;
            right--;
        }
        tmp      = X[left];
        X[left]  = X[right];
        X[right] = tmp;
        right --;
        if(left == right)
            return left + 1;
        left ++;
    }
}

void QuickSort(float x[], int lo, int hi){
int pivot;
    if (lo < hi){
        pivot = Partition(x, lo, hi);
        QuickSort(x, lo, pivot);
        QuickSort(x, pivot+1, hi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again thanks for you and @CiaoPan 's help. After reading this and the explanation of the algorithm I was finally able to do my assignment. I assumed that a final output of a sorted number was expected but after reading the question again I realized that it was only asking to list the return value and partitioned version of the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of the algorithm**

The routine re-arranges data so that items less than the supplied `xmiddle` value remain on the left side of the array (at smaller indices) and items greater than `xmiddle` are put to the right part (at bigger indices). The return value is a length of the left part.

Variables `left` and `right` scan the array from both ends to find items which should be swapped.

The 'left loop' (starting at line 4) increments the `left` index until it finds an item greater than or equal to `xmiddle` (line 5) or until it reaches the `right` position (line 6). As `right` is initially the last index of the array (and later it can only be decremented), the loop must eventually stop incrementing `left`.

If the `left` index meets `right` then all items below and at `left` are less than `xmiddle`, so `left+1` is returned as a length of the left subarray. Note that if `xmiddle` is chosen bigger than all items of the array, the return value is equal to the array's length (`ndata`).

If `left` stops at an item greater than or equal to `xmiddle`, then the 'otherwise' branch at line 9 executes and the 'right loop' starts. Similar to the `left loop` it decrements `right`, stepping over all items greater than or equal to `xmiddle` until the `right` index meets `left`. If the two indices meet (line 11), then all items below them are less than, and all items above and at them are greater than or equal to `xmiddle`; then `left` is returned as the length of the left part.

On the other hand, if the `right` index finds an item less than `xmiddle` (i.e. not satisfying the condition at line 10), then it needs to be swapped with the item at index `left`, which is greater than or equal to `xmiddle` (it didn't satisfy the condition at line 5). Then the 'otherwise' branch at line 13 is executed.

The branch swaps the two values (line 14), so both left and right part become one item longer. To reflect that, the `right` index is decremented (line 15) and then compared to `left`. If they got equal (line 16), i.e. we swapped adjacent items, the partitioning is done, so `left+1` is returned as a length of the left part. Otherwise `left` gets incremented (line 17) and we exit the 'right loop' (line 18) and proceed to the closing brace of the 'left loop' in line 20, which brings the execution back to line 4.

Then again `left` gets incremented (that is the left part grows) until it meets the right part or finds an item to be swapped. And so on...

The loops invariants are:

- `left` ≤ `right`
- `X[i] < xmiddle` for `0 ≤ i < left`
- `X[i] ≥ xmiddle` for `right < i < ndata`

and the un-tested part of the array gets reduced (the difference `right - left` is decremented) at least by 1 in every iteration of a loop.