# Why doesn't my quicksort implemented in Java work?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Here's the code:

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        sort(a, 0, a.length-1);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        if(hi <= lo) return;
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, j-1);
        sort(a, j+1, hi);
    }

    private static int partition(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        int v = a[0];
        int i = lo, j = hi+1;
        while(true) {
            while(a[++i] < v) {
                if(i == hi) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(a[--j] > v) {
                if(j == lo) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i >= j) {
                break;
            } else {
                exch(a, i, j);
            }
        }
        exch(a, lo, j);    // <- exchange the value of a[lo] and a[j]
        return j;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I know it's a really simple algorithm but just cannot figure out where the problem is.

Please help me, thx in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the example code noted as [quicksort with conventional pre-increment / pre-decrement Hoare partition scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002448/partition-algorithm-with-two-loops-c/34012719#34012719) in this other thread. Change float to int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the `partition` function of yours has a bug. The vertex (pivot) `v` that you are selecting should be set to `a[lo]` and not `a[0]` everytime.

And, then set `i = lo + 1` and `j = hi`

Comment: When `v` equals `a[lo]`, then, `i = lo` would do one redundant iteration. It will give the correct result though.

Comment: Sorting an already sorted array will be worst case using v=a[lo]. Use v = a[(lo + hi)/2], and then the checks for i==hi and j==lo are no longer needed.

Comment: @rcgldr, I can always produce a worst case if you are choosing a "fixed" (formula for) pivot, like `a[lo]` or `a[(lo+hi)/2]` etc. If you truly want to avoid it, choose a random pivot, like `v = a[rand]`, where `rand = random number in range (lo,hi)`

Comment: Yes there's always a worst case unless you resort to [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) with n/5 factor (or n/7, n/9, ...), but then it's slow. A fixed centor pivot will still have worst cases, but at least sorted or reverse sorted arrays are handled. Also [quicksort with Hoare partition scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002448/partition-algorithm-with-two-loops-c/34012719#34012719) doesn't need those i==hi and j==lo checks.